# Make ReadyBoost use SATA instead of USB drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, sata, readyboost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable ReadyBoost on a second internal HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/30025/enable-readyboost-on-a-second-internal-hdd)

As far as I know, ReadyBoost only works on USB flash media.  I have a 4GB SATA SSD, and I thought it would be interesting to use it as a ReadyBoost cache.

Is it possible to force Win 7 to use a SATA drive for ReadyBoost?

Comment: Works fine on several SSDs hooked up on MB SATA connections here. Right click the drive, select properties, select ReadyBoost tab and I am able to check use this device.

Comment: similar question, here...http://superuser.com/questions/116330/i-recently-attached-an-external-hd-with-esata-in-windows-7-when-i-try-to-enable